# Breakpoint on continue in if statement not hit

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

In the following code, both `a` and `b` are outputs of generator functions, and could evaluate to `None` or have a value.

```
def testBehaviour(self):
  a = None
  b = 5

  while True:
    if not a or not b:
      continue
    print('blaat')
```

If I put breakpoints (using Visual Studio Code) on the line with the `continue` statement, and the line with the `print` statement, neither is hit. The `print` statement is not called, and the loop just keeps running indefinitely as expected, but I would expect that breakpoints are hit.

If I change the code to one of the following:

```
def testBehaviour(self):
  a = None
  b = 5

  while True:
    if not a:
      continue
    print('blaat')
```

or:

```
def testBehaviour(self):
  a = None
  b = 5

  while True:
    if not a or not b:
      c = 'dummy'
      continue
    print('blaat')
```

And again place breakpoints on the lines with the `continue` and `print` statements, the breakpoints are hit.

Can anyone tell me why the breakpoints are not hit? It seems to not happen only in Visual Studio Code, because our code-coverage tool also states that the `continue` statement was not called.

This is on python 2.7 on Windows 7, 32 bit.

Comment: You may get a clue by looking at the bytecode being generated for the different versions of the function — which you can see via: `dis.dis(testBehaviour)`.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for your suggestion! In the bytecode I don't see much difference either, they both use the `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`, `JUMP_ABSOLUTE`, and `JUMP_FORWARD`. Do you know what specific things to look for?

Comment: this is python-3 print statement

Comment: @rioV8 `print('Whatever')` is valid Python 2.7 code as well... But it does not seem to matter what type of statement is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an optimization in the opcodes, the compiler recognizes the `if expr: continue`.

When using `if not a or not b:`

```
 11          12 SETUP_LOOP              35 (to 50)
        >>   15 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (True)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       49

 12          21 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             24 UNARY_NOT
             25 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        15
             28 LOAD_FAST                2 (b)
             31 UNARY_NOT
             32 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       41

 13          35 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           15
             38 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 41)

 14     >>   41 LOAD_CONST               2 ('blaat')
             44 PRINT_ITEM
             45 PRINT_NEWLINE
             46 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           15
        >>   49 POP_BLOCK
        >>   50 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             53 RETURN_VALUE
```

The line `25 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        15` jumps back to the start of the while loop (line 15) if `not a` is true. It never reaches the line of the continue statement `35 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           15`

If you switch the values of `a` and `b` this test case works.

If you rewrite the test expression to `if not ( a and b ):` you get the following opcodes

```
 11          12 SETUP_LOOP              33 (to 48)
        >>   15 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (True)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       47

 12          21 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             24 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    30
             27 LOAD_FAST                2 (b)
        >>   30 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        39

 13          33 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           15
             36 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 39)

 14     >>   39 LOAD_CONST               2 ('blaat')
             42 PRINT_ITEM
             43 PRINT_NEWLINE
             44 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           15
        >>   47 POP_BLOCK
        >>   48 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             51 RETURN_VALUE
```

And that always works and is faster. The `not` operations are optimized into the jump test statements

Comment: Wow, thanks for this detailed answer! Now I understand it!

Comment: @DrDonut This behaviour is also for Python 3. This makes it difficult to debug a program. Single stepping has some strange behavior and from your question setting breakpoints will not always hit. And letting a novice programmer first examine the generated opcodes to see if there are no optimizations performed is not correct. This should be done only when you request a compilation with optimizations.