# debug python in vscode but failed to stop at breakpoints

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I try to debug my python script in VSCode, but it failed to stop at the breakpoint.
I click the debug button, but it seems like nothing happends. The codes never stop at my breakpoint!

Here's my launch.json. I use anaconda virtual envs as interpreter.
Please help me out, thanks!!!

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: 当前文件",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "/home/linda/.conda/envs/py3/bin/python",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: maybe this is the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62389415/9938317

Comment: I tried to switch the interpreter to local python environment and this problem has gone. But I DO want to use virtual envs! I have no idea how to configure it to make the debug work in conda virtual envs...

Comment: @CutePuppy Since the current python debugging function is provided by the python extension, it is recommended that you could try to disabled other extensions and reinstall the python extension. In addition, you could try to use other versions of python extensions, For example: (v2020.7.96456).